# Trying to Create a HTML app which will run on multiple computers

Tags: html

I am trying to create a simple app heres the scenario:

I have 3 computers (or screens) and 1 tablet
I have 3 different videos

I want to create an application that will be started by tablet (pressing start) which will run 3 seperate videos on 3 different screens.

These screens when idle should show a specific photo (a brand for example)

And tablet will show all 3 videos at the same time on its screen when pressed start.

Can i code this quickly with html?

thank a lot and any help is appriciated :)

Comment: While HTML could be a building block, it's not sufficient to solve your scenario.  There are a few pieces of information missing here - 1. are the devices connected to internet, or any network - and if so, are they all on the same network? 2. What kind of OS are the devices running?  3. What kind of scripting or programming language do you know?  4. Do you have access to a server where you could host some sort of a controller/webserver?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the computers are on same, local network, Win10x64, html, and visualscripting on UE4, can wamp server be used for a local server controller?

Comment: Excellent.  Here are some things to get started.  WAMP is probably an overkill.  UE4 isn't going to much of help here.  What you need is to be able to have the 3 computers listen to instructions from the tablet and execute those.  It's probably easier to make those 3 computers run some sort of server and the tablet could connect to each and issue requests.  I'd recommend reading up on nodejs for the server side (you'll find plenty of help on Stackoverflow with this route).

Comment: @slacker Thanks a lot for your help! I will check on node.js, much appriciated.